# Create a common column in node-red from different files

Tags: csv, node-red

I am working with 2 csv and I want to join them and assing a column named "Home" with the value "1A" referring to the 1st csv (in each line) and "2A" referring to the 2nd.

Please help me with the function.

I am trying different functions but they don´t work. I have:

- Node inject: msg.topic = 1A (for the 1st csv) + Node read file: with csv + Node csv: with columns names
- Node inject: msg.topic = 2A (for the 2nd csv) + Node read file: with csv + Node csv: with columns names

And after that a join of both csv and a function to obtain the final one (does not work).

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76472765/edit) the question to show the function you have tried and explain what is wrong with the output. Without the code we really can't help (we will not just supply code based on a list of requirements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important that you put the join with the topic. I would do the function this way:

```js
var data_def = []
for (var number in msg.payload){
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.payload[number].length; i++){
        data_def.push({
            "Home": number,
            "col1": msg.payload[number][i].col1
        })
    }
}
msg.payload = data_def
return msg;
```

There is another option to assing each topic:

1. Node inject (do not change anything)
2. Node change for each csv with msg.topic = the name you want